# tikz coordinate at a coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to coordinate a node at another coordinate. However, I receive an error message. 
Maybe one of you have an idea how to solve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5,scale=1,thick]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$Employment$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Wages$};
\draw[-] (5,0) coordinate (d_1) -- (0,4) coordinate (d_2);
\draw[-] (2.7,0) coordinate (s_1) -- (2.7,6) coordinate (s_2);
\draw[-] (1.5,0) coordinate (s_3)-- (1.5,6) coordinate (s_4);
\coordinate [label= right:$B$] (b) at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_1--s_2);
\fill[red] (b) circle (2pt);
\coordinate [label= right:$A$] (a) at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_3--s_4);
\coordinate [label= left:$W1$] (w1) at (0,$(b)$);
\draw[-] (w1) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$(' (in '$(b').
See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
l.82 ...rdinate [label= left:$W1$] (w1) at (0,$(b)
                                              $);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your real question is something like: How to get a point on the y-axis at the height of some other point?

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here is one, using `\path let`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5,scale=1,thick]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$Employment$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Wages$};
\draw[-] (5,0) coordinate (d_1) -- (0,4) coordinate (d_2);
\draw[-] (2.7,0) coordinate (s_1) -- (2.7,6) coordinate (s_2);
\draw[-] (1.5,0) coordinate (s_3)-- (1.5,6) coordinate (s_4);
\coordinate [label= right:$B$] (b) at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_1--s_2);
% moved down so it's not overdrawn by the blue line
%\fill[red] (b) circle (2pt);
\coordinate [label= right:$A$] (a) at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_3--s_4);
\path let \p1=(b) in
  coordinate [label= left:$W1$] (w1) at (0,\y1); % point on y-axis
\draw[blue] (w1) -- (b);
\fill[red] (b) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

- added new coordinate `O` for axis origin
- used orthogonal coordinate system `-|` for determining coordinate `W1`
- instead $Employment$ and $Wages$ use `\textit{Employment}` and `\textit{Wages}` respectively

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
% axis
\coordinate (O) at (0,0); % <-- added
\draw[->] (O) -- (6,0) node[right] {\textit{Employment}};
\draw[->] (O) -- (0,6) node[above] {\textit{Wages}};
%
\draw (5.0,0) coordinate (d_1) -- (0.0,4) coordinate (d_2);
\draw (2.7,0) coordinate (s_1) -- (2.7,6) coordinate (s_2);
\draw (1.5,0) coordinate (s_3) -- (1.5,6) coordinate (s_4);
%
\coordinate [label= right:$B$] (b) at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_1--s_2);
\draw[blue] (b -| O) node[left,text=black] {$W1$} -- (b);
\fill[red]  (b) circle (2pt);
\coordinate [label= right:$A$] (a)  at (intersection of d_1--d_2 and s_3--s_4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all! Understand it now and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Eddy, if answer solve your problem (on the best way), you can accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but I can see that on the line that TeX identifies as having the error, you have the coordinate specification `(0,$(b)$)`.  This is not a parseable TikZ coordinate.  If you want it at the same location as `b`, then just write `(b)`.  If you want to do something more complicated then what you do depends on what that more complicated thing is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 
I would like do what you just wrote, using location `b` as another coordinate. After removing  `$ $`, I still receive the following error message
`Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function b' (in '(b').`

Comment: @Eddy to clarify: you probably wrote `at (0,(b));`, but you should just write `at (b);`

Comment: I just added the picture that I attempt to create, but i failed to draw the blue line beacuse of the error message. Thank you.

Comment: @Eddy: (b) is a point... You just need the Y coordinate there... not the whole point (b). Search for x,y coordinates in tikz to learn about it until someone give the final answer